# Convert byte inputstream to base64 XPages Scriptblock

Tags: javascript, base64, byte, xpages

Please tell me what should I do to this code, I'am about to convert a byte data to base64 string. The code below will only just translate the image file to inputstream and I can't figure out how am I going to convert it to base64.

```
var MyView:NotesView = database.getView("uploadforms");
var uploadPhoto:NotesDocumentCollection = MyView.getAllDocumentsByKey("uploadphoto");
var input:java.io.InputStream = uploadPhoto.getFirstDocument().getAttachment("photo").getInputStream();

var data = -1;
var myArray = new Array();

while ((data = input.read()) != -1) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *sun.misc.BASE64Encoder* class for this:

```
var MyView:NotesView = database.getView("uploadforms");
var uploadPhoto:NotesDocumentCollection = MyView.getAllDocumentsByKey("uploadphoto");
var input:java.io.InputStream = uploadPhoto.getFirstDocument().getAttachment("photo").getInputStream();

var base64Enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
var output = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
base64Enc.encode( input, output );
output.toString()
```

**EDIT:**
As written in the comments, better use *com.ibm.misc.BASE64Encoder*.

Comment: thank you sou much Mr. Sven, is this code going to read all of my images inside my Lotus notes database?

Comment: Hi Sven, I want to test your code given. I want to display the particular base64 on my web page. How can I do that?

Comment: I can't figure out how am I going to do this. please guide me *pray*

Comment: Open the Domino Designer, press *F1*.

Comment: Please be aware that this class is UNSUPPORTED and should not be used in production code. Please use other libraries such as found in apache commons

Comment: @jjtbsomhorst: You are correct that this class is unsupported and there is the chance that it will be removed in the next years. Feel free the edit my response and change it to a version with apache commons encoder.

Comment: @jjtbsomhorst: You mean the Base64Encoder? Luckily there are some others built-in to Domino you can use in XPages: com.ibm.misc.BASE64Encoder, javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, com.ibm.commons.util.io.base64.Base64. So no need to add Apache Commons.